# Write array to Buffer on a specific offset in Node.js

Tags: node.js, node.js-buffer

I wish to add an array to a buffer at a specific offset. This does not work:

```
let buffer = Buffer.alloc(65);

buffer.writeUInt8(0x91, 0);
buffer.write([127, 0, 0, 1 ], 1);
buffer.write("admin", 5);
buffer.write("admin", 31);
```

as it gives me the error:

```
(node:10468) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: argument must be a string
```

Comment: buffer.from maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this works:

```
var buf = Buffer.alloc(10);
buf.fill(Buffer.from([ 0x1, 0x2]), 3, 5 );

console.log(buf);
```

First create a buffer with a length of 10. Fill from position 3 until 5 with array `[ 0x1, 0x2 ]`.